# Saving a Base64 string representing an image on Django database

Tags: django, base64

I'm fairly new to Django and I'm looking for the best way to store Base64 images on my Dajango db/server.

My goal is to be able to send batches of images through http request, therefore it would make sense to send them as encoded Base64 images, I may end up rendering them on a webpage but they will primarily be sent to a desktop application in batches.

After looking through several other posts it looks like there are three approaches and I'm not sure what best fits my needs.

1. Store Base64 string in model TextField
2. Store Base64 string in FileField
3. Store an image in an image field and convert it to Base64 when needed

My concern with option 1 is that storing large textfields in the db will hinder performance, however like I said I'm new so I really don't have any idea.

Option 2 seems to make sense to me as this is similar to how django handles images, by storing them else and just referencing the location in the db.  However, I'm not sure if this is simply because sqlite does not support fields of this type.  I also see the potential for additional overhead, having to open and read files vs just reading a text field.

Lastly option 3 appears to be a rather unattractive option due to my use case, as these base64 images will be primarily sent in batches via http requests so I figured it would be best to store the converted version rather than encode each image upon each request.

I would greatly appreciate any insight the community could offer as to which approach might make the most sense for me to take.  What are your thoughts?

Follow up question, if I intend on converting my database to Postgres does anything change regarding which approach I should take?

Comment: Usually it is better to store files with the filesystem, since a database will encode the data less efficient, and thus require more bandwidth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is better *not* to store binary data in the database. Typically this will requires escaping to create/update/retrieve data, and thus results in less efficient access.

What is usually done is working with a [**`FileField`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#filefield) or an [**`ImageField`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ImageField). For these two model fields, it will store the file in the *file system*, and save the *path* in the database. This will thus reduce the amount of overhead to load or save an object.

You can decide to store a base64 encoding of the file, but likely that will not be more efficient: it means that it requires more time to read the file from the disk. Encoding to base64 is efficient, and therefore it will likely be more efficient to store the file in a compact way and return a base64 that is created in the view.

Comment: Thank you for the response, so would it make sense to store the each image in an ImageField and then encode each to Base64 at the time I want to package a set of photos into http response?

Comment: @KKochiss: by using an `ImageField` you will store the image on the file system. I would however *not* base64 encode it, since that would make files larger, you can encode it in base64 on the fly in the view where you will serve that file.